# Can I have a custom view between two different collectionViews?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I need to achieve a ViewController that is scrollable vertically but also have two collectionviews that scroll with the overall viewcontroller. I have my scrollviews setup but I've read that its bad practice to have a collectionview inside a scrollview.

I also been thinking to use a UICollectionViewController to achieve the scrolling with the view by using a header, but I don't know if I could add a view in between two different collection views.

How do I go on about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having 2 collection views, use 1 collection view with 2 sections and have custom UIViews as your section headers.